# How to read a table and Sql query from Oracle in Pandas?

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, pandas, teradata

I am completely new to Python and pandas. I want to load a some tables and Sql Queries from Oracle and Teradata to pandas Dataframes and want to analyse them. 
I know, we have to create some connection strings to Oracle and Teradata in Pandas. Can you please suggest me them and also add the sample code to read both table and SQL query in that?

Thanks Inadvance

Answer (score 2):

> I don't have Oracle server, so I take Teradata as an example
>
> This is not the only way to to that, just one approach

- Make sure you have installed Teradata ODBC Driver. Please refer to Teradata official website about the steps, I suppose you use Windows (since it is easy to use SQL Assistant to run query against Teradata, that is only on Windows). You can check it in `ODBC Data Source Administrator`
- Install `pyodbc` by the command `pip install pyodbc`. Here is the [official website](https://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/)
- The connection string is `db_conn_str = "DRIVER=Teradata;DBCNAME={url};UID={username};PWD={pwd}"`
- Get a connection object `conn = pyodbc.connect(db_conn_str)`
- Read data from a SQL query to a DataFrame `df = pd.read_sql(sql="select * from tb", con=conn)`

The similar for Oracle, you need to have the driver and the format of ODBC connection string. I know there is a python module from Teradata which supports the connection too, but I just prefer use odbc as it is more generic purpose.

Comment: Very neat and detailed answer ++

Comment: Thanks Zhong Dai. I am getting invalid Syntax when I tried pip install pyodbc.

Comment: @Ramsey use **pip** to install Python package is a basic knowledge to use Python, please refer to Python foundation document to see what was wrong. I guess you don't have the correct **PATH**, or you have not installed **pip**.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Oracle example:

```
import cx_Oracle   #  pip install cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://scott:tiger@host:1521/?service_name=hr')

df = pd.read_sql('select * from table_name', engine)
```

Comment: Thanks MaxU. I am working on Windows machine and Anacoda. I opened Anaconda Prompt and gone to Python3, then I tried pip install cx_Oracle, but I am getting the invalid syntax error for both pyodbc and cx_Oracle. Please help me on this.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+install+python+module+pip&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr#pws=0&gl=us&q=python+how+install+modules+using+pip&*

Comment: Where in this are you using the cx_Oracle module?

Answer (score 0):

One way to query an Oracle DB is with a function like this one:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

def query(sql: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    try: 
        with cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, database, encoding='UTF-8') as connection:
            dataframe = pd.read_sql(sql, con=connection)
        return dataframe
    except cx_Oracle.Error as error: print(error)
    finally: print("Fetch end")
```

here, **sql** corresponds to the query you want to run. Since it´s a string it also supports line breaks in case you are reading the query from a .sql file
eg:

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE\nWHERE <condition>\nGROUP BY <COL_NAME>"
```

or anything you need... it could also be an f-string in case you are using variables.

This function returns a pandas dataframe with the results from the sql string you need.
It also keeps the column names on the dataframe